# C# Save Combobox value and use in sql to display grouped data

Tags: wpf, listview, combobox, designer

this is the code for my ComboBox in xaml file:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" telerik:TextSearch.TextPath="Name" Margin="0 0 10 0"
            IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableFunds}"
                             DisplayMemberPath="Perioada"
                        SelectedValuePath="Perioada" 
                                SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Perioada}" 
                             SelectedIndex="0" 
            SelectionBoxTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxSimpleTemplate}" SelectionChanged="RadComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

The combobox display some dates (Years and Months), where the client can choose one. Then, I need to display in a listview all dates for the selected period :

```
<ListView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SalesGroupedByPartners}" Margin="0,0,10,0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView >
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Perioada" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Perioada}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Nume Client" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Client}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Suma">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Width="120" TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Suma, StringFormat=N2}" Margin="-6,0" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

in .cs file I have a method which is empty :

`private void RadComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
}`

I tried to create a string in this method and save the result of my ComboBox, but can not access it, because my ComboBox have not a name (  ).

Or , I can send dirrectly the choise to sql file .... :

declare @Period
set @Period = client choise **(here I don't know to call from ComboBox)**

and to display in ListView :

select * from table
where Period = @Period

[image: BomboBox and ListView designer]

Comment: **I tried to create a string in this method and save the result of my ComboBox, but can not access it, because my ComboBox have not a name ( ).** You don't need a name when you are using the MVVM pattern and bindings like you already do ;) Isn't the value in the property `Perioada`?

Comment: Perioada is just a column in .sql file which display all dates. Depending by this selection, the new .sql query need to have a line "where Period = @Period (selected period by client) and d

Comment: That's why it's a bad pattern when you bind database objects to your view. You should use viewmodels and bind their properties. Then it wouldn't be a problem to get the value from the `ComboBox` or any other control.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to create a string in this method and save the result of my ComboBox, but can not access it, because my ComboBox have not a name ( ).

You could get a reference to the `RadComboBox` by casting the `sender` argument in your event handler:

```
private void RadComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadComboBox comboBox = sender as Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadComboBox;
    object value = comboBox.SelectedValue;
    //...
}
```

But since you bind to a `Perioada` property, you could also retrieve the currently selected value from this property.

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'RadComboBox' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) really, I need a namespace named as my ComboBox? :|

Comment: Add the following using statement at the top of the code file or use the fully qualified name as per my edited answer: `using Telerik.Windows.Controls;`.

Answer (score 0):

solved :D

in xaml.cs file needed to add some code :

```
    cn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Properties.Resources.SalesGroupedByPartners, cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 100;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Perioada", Perioada);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(salesGroupedByPartners);

            cn.Close();
```

and

```
var negativeRows = new List<SalesGroupedByPartners>();

        foreach (var v in viewModel.SalesGroupedByPartners)
        {
            if (v.Perioada == "@Perioada")
            {
                negativeRows.Add(v);
            }
        }
```